# How to use two database connections dynamically to avoid code doublets

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two database connections.

```
private MyEntities1 db1;
private MyEntities2 db2;
```

Those two connections have the same tables. They are both generated by adding a ADO.NET template using existing database.

The two MSSQL connections will retreive data from two old MySQL databases. It is a migration.

```
        if (isContext1)
        {
            var transactionContext = this.db1.Database.BeginTransaction();
            this.db1.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(setIdentityInsertOn);
            this.db1.MyTable.AddRange(res);
            this.db1.SaveChanges();
            this.db1.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(setIdentityInsertOff);
            transactionContext.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            var transactionContext = this.db2.Database.BeginTransaction();
            this.db2.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(setIdentityInsertOn);
            this.db2.MyTable.AddRange(res);
            this.db2.SaveChanges();
            this.db2.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(setIdentityInsertOff);
            transactionContext.Commit();
        }
```

where setIdentityOn and Off is:

```
var database = (isContext1) ? "db1" : "db2";

var setIdentityInsertOn = string.Format("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [{0}].[dbo].[MyTable] ON", database);
```

Now, I have many code doublets. I tried to solve this by creating an array holding both connections.

```
var contextHolder = new Dictionary<string, DbContext>();
contextHolder["db1"] = new MyEntities1();
contextHolder["db2"] = new MyEntities2();
```

Unfortunatelly this does not work; I guess it is because I am saying that the second type of the dictionary is DbContext, so the compiler doesn't know the entites.

If I could just say something like this, all my problems would be solved:

```
var context = if(isContext1) ? this.db1 : this.db2;
```

My Question:

How to avoid those if/else constructs? How can I do this more "dynamically". Is this even possible?

Thanks for your time and best regards

Comment: If the two schemas have the same tables, why have you created two separate context types at all? Why not just `MyEntities` and pass the connection string into the constructor?

Comment: Ah, good thinking. I guess that would work. Thank you very much. Separately from this, assumed the schemas would be differ, how would one solve this?

Comment: Well if the schemas differed, you shouldn't expect to be able to perform the same operations on them, so you wouldn't be able to use a common type... that feels like it's an entirely different situation.